# How to set Windows 11 Active Hours 24h format?

Tags: windows-11, regional-settings

I have these settings:
[image]

I want to have this settings (and similar ones, if they exist) in 24-hour format BUT ALSO keep my display language English.
My Clock setting is already German / 24h.

#### Is there a way, to set the ENTIRE UI of all the Windows 11 settings to 24h format, including the Windows Update Active Hours, while keeping it English?

BTW I find it pretty bad to use 12h format here, since it can be ambiguous, as even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#Confusion_at_noon_and_midnight) states.
[image]

Ironically the UI for changing time manually is 24h format.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I agree that this is a real mess :

[image]

However, only Microsoft can fix it. All you can do is signal this
inconsistency via the Feedback Hub.